# Add css class to item on checkout xml

Tags: magento2, checkout, class, quoteitem

how can i add a css class eg.: class="myClass" to an item on checkout xml?

for example

```
<item name="after-place-agreements" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">after-place-agreements</item>
    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">before-place-order</item>
    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/payment/before-place-order</item>
    </item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="agreementss" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/view/checkout-agreements</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">100</item>
            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">after-place-agreements</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">checkoutAgreements</item>
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Comment: Why don't you add class in this file `vendor/magento/module-checkout-agreements/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/checkout-agreements.html`...Note: override in your theme

Comment: because i have one component for different fileds bu i can create a dedicated one if there are no other solution :) thank a lot i will try